# Obfuscating return values in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am writing an app and for security reasons I'd like to obfuscate the value returned from a static method.  The result from calling the static methods from `ClassA` should be a `BOOL` but I'd like to make it as hard as possible for an attacker to get the real value of the return (i.e. I do not want to return a `BOOL`, I want to return some junk that looks random but is somehow meaningful).

```
// in ClassA
returnValue = [ClassB staticMethod];
BOOL actaulReturnValue = // some magic to de-obfuscate returnValue
```

For example: returning 1024 bits of mostly random junk but somewhere is a single meaningful digit (possibly a different bit every time).

Another example: returning 10 or so seemingly random digits, but if those 10 digits appear in the first 1000 digits of pi then the real value is `TRUE` (accepting the fact that there will be a 1 in 10,000,000,000 false positive rate).

Those are two examples I can think of, but I leave it to the stackoverflow community to help think of other (possibly better) ways of doing this.  Bonus points if you can also provide code.

**EDIT:** The harder to reverse engineer the better. If I can run cycript and determine the secret the game is over.
**EDIT 2:** Even if an attacker knows how I am obfuscating the return value it should still be hard (if not impossible) to figure out the real value (which is also a problem with my second example)

**EDIT 3:** I preform pen tests of iOS apps for a living.  I understand anything in memory can be read because I do it on a daily basis for clients.  I am also not trying to imply that obfuscation and security are the same thing.  That being said, I am trying to figure out a way to prevent an attacker from patching a single API call to always return FALSE.

Thanks!

Comment: I am a security consultant, please don't patronize me.

Comment: sorry that you took this personal. I honestly did not intend to make you feel uncomfortable.

Comment: It's okay.  I was just hoping for helpful answers and I got the first two people implying I didn't understand what I was talking about.

Comment: @Corey this is called StackOverflow effect. Anything got flagged by a relatively high-reputation profile will be agreed by the rest. Your question/answer gets voted down, closed or even deleted. StackOverflow is not a place to ask this kind of question.

Comment: @Corey did you find anything useful on this?

Answer (score 5):

I'll be honest with you: don't bother. Here's why:

***At some point you will need to load the un-encrypted value into memory***

Suppose you craft your method to obfuscate its return value - what happens when you actually need to use that value? You un-obfuscate it *and load it into a variable, which exists in memory*. And then your attacker just needs to inspect that memory location, which on a jailbroken device and with some additional tools is trivial.

You will never get over this problem. There's absolutely no point doing what you're trying to do. You're basically doomed to failure. If you're interested in making your apps more secure [there's a great book published by O'Reilly](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023234.do) that I found very useful.

Comment: @ltx I understand all the ways this could potentially fail, I am not interested in that right now because I have already considered it.  I have already read that book front to back multiple times.  I teach people how to use cycript.

Comment: With PIE and ASLR, inspecting memory is not as trivial.  Sure, they can use cycript or gdb but even with those I'm sure there are ways to do what I'd like.  An analogy would be throwing all the pieces of 100 different puzzles together and throwing away the picture of the finished product.  Sure, given enough time someone will make the puzzle, but at least I didn't make it easy.

Comment: This is why your name will never be remembered in the security field.  Before 1977 people with your mindset called Rivest, Shamir, and Adleman crazy for thinking they could invent a system of encryption with used two separate keys (one of which was **public**), luckily they didn't listed or we wouldn't have RSA or the dozens of protocols which stem from it.  Hard problems require hard solutions.  If you're not interested in helping then I don't need your feedback.

Comment: @lxt -1 for the mindset. While it is true that eventually the value is decrypted in the memory, it can still delay the attackers. The more protections you have, the more delayed the attacker is and the less determined he is.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some tricky bitwise operations on your result to get some bit index, and check the bit at that index to see if it is set or not, for example.

In the following example:

- Given then 32-bit cryptic result, I compute the XOR of the 2nd and 4th bytes of your cryptic result, and then again XOR the upper 4 bits with the lower 4 bits. This gives me a 4-bit result that can be interpreted as an `index` between 0 and 15.
- Then I use this index to know which bit I need to check in the remaining 2 bytes: I concatenate the 3rd byte and the 1st byte to have a 16-bit word, and check the `index`-th bit of that word to see if the bit is set or not.

Here is the decoding function I tested:

```
-(BOOL)decodeCrypticResult:(long)crypticResult
{
  u_int8_t* bytes = (u_int8_t*)&crypticResult;

  u_int8_t xor = bytes[1] ^ bytes[3];
  u_int8_t idx = ((xor>>4)&0xF) ^ (xor&0xF); // value in range [0..15]
  u_int16_t word = ((bytes[2]<<8) & 0xFF00) | bytes[0]; // bytes 2 and 0 concatenated into a 16-bit word
  BOOL res = (word >> idx) & 1; // check the idx-th bit of this word
  return res;
}
```

To generate your cryptic result to return either a cryptic `YES` or `NO` from the `staticMethod` of your library, that's quite easy:

- Generate a random 32-bit number
- Compute the bit index as above from the representation of this random number
- set or unset (depending of the `BOOL` you need to return) the corresponding bit in the 1st or 3rd byte of your random number before returning it

So this gives the following code:

```
-(long)returnCrypticBoolValue:(BOOL)boolValue
{
  u_int32_t crypticResult = arc4random();
  u_int8_t* bytes = (u_int8_t*)&crypticResult;

  u_int8_t xor = bytes[1] ^ bytes[3];
  u_int8_t idx = ((xor>>4)&0xF) ^ (xor&0xF); // value in range [0..15]
  if (boolValue) {
    // set the idx-th bit of byte 2 or 0
    bytes[ (idx&8)?2:0 ] |=  (1 << (idx&7));
  } else {
    // unset the idx-th bit of byte 2 or 0
    bytes[ (idx&8)?2:0 ] &= ~(1 << (idx&7));
  }
  return crypticResult;
}
```

Comment: Referring to EDIT #3, this will fail as the attacker may simply patch the boolValue parameter into being FALSE/NO with really little effort.

Comment: It's funny how fast you're willing give up.

Comment: @Till that's not the question. We're all aware that obfuscation is not encryption and that's not securing the stuff. The OP do know about it, he specifically said it multiple times in his comments and even in his EDIT #3 you're refering too. You made your point, which is that what the OP asks is not a way to secure some code on its own, we understand it all even the OP itself, but this was not the original question and the OP still semms interested in suggestions for **obfuscating** its value, so that even if it not encrypted at least the API does not make it simple to guess at first sight.